# Picture-Slideshow not Showing all Pictures

Tags: css, slideshow, css-grid

Hi I recently created a picture slideshow at the following link (https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/NaNGpq?editors=0100), in which all the pictures show perfectly in the slideshow.

Here is the HTML code for this slideshow:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS Slideshow Test</title>
</head>

<body> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="Faces Wheels">
      <figure>
        <img      src="https://s26.postimg.org/cso75hjqh/Faces_Wheels_Dodge_Charger_Front_3-_Quarter_View.jpg
" width="360" height="270">
      <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/63hnpgyeh/Faces_Wheels_Dodge_Charger_Side_3-_Quarter_View.jpg" width="360" height="270">
      <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/9pnh244rt/Faces_Wheels_Dodge_Charger_Side_3-_Quarter_View.jpg" width="360" height="270">
      <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/jlok1rajt/Faces_Wheels_Dodge_Charger_Side_View.jpg" width="360" height="270">
        </figure>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none; 
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  left:30%;
}

div.Faces.Wheels {
  width: 3000px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  width:500px;
  float:none;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.Faces.Wheels figure{
overflow: hidden;
height: 500px;
}


.Faces.Wheels figure img{
width: 100%
float: left;
}

.Faces.Wheels figure{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
animation: 15s rims infinite;
}


@keyframes rims {
    0%{
        left: -40%;     
    }
  50%{
        left:0%;     
    }
  100%{
        left:-40%;     
    }

}
```

However, when I try to integrate the code into my other project [here](https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/Xevyqq/) , all the pictures in the slideshow aren't sliding across...infact there seems to be some pictures stacked vertically and hidden. Can you tell me what is causing this? Thanks in advance for your help

HTML for new project, where I'm integrating the slideshow:

```
<div class="Fourth Row">
        <div class="container">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/7uayt1hjf3/378c87079dddbfe1d78c9f892695626fl-m0xd-w1020_h770_q80.jpg" width="360" height="270"/>
      <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krrfz/extralarge.jpg" width="360" height="270"/>
      <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/6yehdl959r/gen_Mid.09186160_1.jpg" width="360" height="270"/>
      <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8tr267l5fz/ISaly9e2xn0r8r1000000000.jpg" width="360" height="270"/>
      <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krz5r/ISinl3p5sts48e1000000000_1.jpg" width="360" height="270"/>
        </figure>  
      </div> 
      <div class ="Slideshow Description">
        <p>
          We are Installation Experts! We
Offer Customized Installation for Both Residential and Commercial Properties
        </p>
      </div>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.Main{
  /*background-color: yellow;*/
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:(3, 1fr);
}

.Header.Box {
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /*background-color: red;*/
  grid-gap: 0;
}

#One, #Two, #Three {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;  
}

.Second.Row{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.Third.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /*background-color: green;*/
}

.Fourth.Row{
  display: grid;
  gris-template: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: blue;
}


/**{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none; 
}*/

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: left;
  top: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  left:30%;
}

  /*.Fourth.Row {
  width: 3000px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}*/

figure {
  width:500px;
  float:none;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.Fourth.Row{
overflow: hidden;
height: 500px;
}

.Fourth.Row figure img{
width: 100%
float: left;
}

.Fourth.Row figure{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 5 0;
left: 0;
animation: 15s rims infinite;
}


@keyframes rims {
    0%{
        left: -40%;     
    }
  50%{
        left:0%;     
    }
  100%{
        left:-40%;     
    }

}

.Slideshow.Description{
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

I've realized that this part of the code from my original slideshow is what enables all the pictures to slide across

```
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: left;
  top: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  left:30%;
}
```

I can't figure out, **however, how to configure the above code** in my new project to enable the pictures to slide across the slideshow.